# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed, opening xml tags

Tags: php, xml, parsing

This snippet of code use to work perfectly, nothing has changed except now it's giving off errors.

```
function wrapOutput($str){
    header('content-type: text/xml; charset: utf-8');
    $o = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . PHP_EOL;
    $o .= ' <rss version="2.0"
                xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
                xmlns:amp="http://www.adobe.com/amp/1.0">' . PHP_EOL;
    $o .= '    <channel>' . PHP_EOL;
    $o .= $str;
    $o .= '    </channel>' . PHP_EOL;
    $o .= '  </rss>' . PHP_EOL;
    return $o;
}
```

Something is going wrong and turning the xml tags into `<'xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"'>`

Which results into the following error
`XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://localhost/mrss.php?feed=test
Line Number 1, Column 2:<'xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"'>
-^`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is de quotes, beacause XML read like eval(), sou u can try escape \"\"   quotes

Comment: Tried escaping doesn't work, also tried swapping around the quotes from single to doubles. It's a string so should output as such